# How to get all versions of an hbase cell in a spark newAPIHadoopRDD?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-spark

I know when you use the Get API you can set `MAX_VERSION_COUNT` to get all versions of a cell. But I didn' t find any documentation on how to get all versions of cell with a map operation of spark newAPIHadoopRDD. I' ve tried with a naive result.getColumnCells() and it returns only 1 result. How can I set `MAX_VERSION_COUNT` in spark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a look at source code of `TableInputFormat` I found it reads configuration from `hbase.mapreduce.scan.maxversions`. So setting it like this works:

```
val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()    
conf.set("hbase.mapreduce.scan.maxversions", "VERSION_YOU_WANT")
val hBaseRDD = sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, classOf[TableInputFormat],
  classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable],
  classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result])
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this but I am still getting the latest version. I have passed the config like-
 conf.set("hbase.mapreduce.scan.maxversions", "10") 
to get the last 10 version of every record.

Comment: Did you also use result.getColumnCells()?